# Как перерисовать объект класса Component или его класса-наследника ТОЛЬКО по нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: java, графика

У меня есть окно с кнопкой, текстовым полем, куда я ввожу массив координат `x` и `y` и областью графика (Свой класс `GraphicsArea` с переопределенным методом `paint(Graphics g)`), в которой нужно нарисовать график зависимости `x` и `y`.  Если я добавляю область графика в конструкторе окна,

```
 add (GraphicsArea area = new GraphicsArea());
```

то эта область рисуется сразу (при запуске приложения) Если я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
// тут graphicsArea — приватное поле

public void drawGraphic (){
    graphicsArea = new GraphicsArea();this.add(graphicsArea);
    graphicsArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));
    this.repaint();


}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource()==runBut){
        drawGraphic();
        repaint();
    }
```

То перерисовки объекта по нажатии на кнопку вообще не происходит.

А если я определяю область графика внутри конструктора главного окна

```
    JPanel graphicsPanel = new JPanel();

    graphicsPanel.add(graphicsArea);
    add(graphicsPanel);
    graphicsArea.setVisible(false);
```

И делаю при нажатии на кнопку рисование этого объекта и делаю его снова видимым, то при первом нажатии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при развертывании окна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И втором нажатии на кнопку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снова свернули окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Мое предположение, что из за метода `repaint()` главного окна, который вызывается каждый раз при сворачивании-разворачивании. Если это так, то как этот метод можно отключить, если вообще можно?

И второе, как можно сделать так, чтобы при втором нажатии на кнопку не вылезала вторая область графика?

Добавляю два полных класса вкладки с графиком

```
   //область графика 
   package TextEditor.graphicsModul;

   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

   public class GraphicsArea extends JPanel {

@Override
public void paint (Graphics g){
    Graphics2D painter = (Graphics2D)g;
    painter.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    painter.drawRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    painter.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    painter.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

    for (int i = 1 ; i< 21; i++){
        painter.drawLine(getX()+20, i*20, getWidth()-20, i*20);
    }


  }

}

 // Сама вкладка
 package TextEditor.graphicsModul;

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;


 public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private double xn , yn, y;
private GraphicsArea graphicsArea = new GraphicsArea();
private JButton runBut = new JButton("Апроксиммировать");

private JTextArea PointsInputArea = new JTextArea();
private  Rectangle menuArea;
//private Rectangle2D.Double graphicsArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(xn, yn, getWidth()*3/4d, getHeight());
private JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel GraphicsPanel;


public GUI(){


    setSize(getWidth(),getHeight());
    FlowLayout manuLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT,10,10);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    JPanel menuItemsPanel = new JPanel();
    menuItemsPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuItemsPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    PointsInputArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, this.getHeight()));
    menuPanel.setLayout(manuLayout);
    menuItemsPanel.add(PointsInputArea);
    menuItemsPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    menuPanel.add(menuItemsPanel);
    menuItemsPanel.add(runBut);
    runBut.addActionListener(this);
    add(menuPanel);
    JPanel graphicsPanel = new JPanel();

    graphicsPanel.add(graphicsArea);
    add(graphicsPanel);
    graphicsArea.setVisible(false);


    setVisible(true);

}






public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource()==runBut){
        graphicsArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,900));
        graphicsArea.paint(this.getGraphics());
        graphicsArea.setVisible(true);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: скорей всего из-за компановки окна - надо смотреть. Можете дать ссылку на проект?

Comment: @Z.John Добавил два полных класса вкладки.

Comment: graphicsArea.paint(this.getGraphics()); тут вы рисуете непосредственно на поверхности вкладки, для обновления вашего графика попробуйте graphicsArea.updateUI();

Comment: Как вы хотите чтоб оно в конечном варианте работало? Сейчас слева у вас область тянется и кнопка за область экрана уползает

Comment: @Z.John в конечном варианте я хочу, зарезервировать место под graphicsArea, но не показывать его, а при нажатии на кнопку вызвать отрисовку области с графиком, графики различные, смотря какие введут точки х и y

Comment: А вы меню принципиально так сделали? Просто можно проще. Можно использовать например JToolBox

Comment: @Z.John Хотелось бы не использовать сторонние библиотеки, а обойтись swing (вроде такого класса как JToolBox нет в  библиотеке.)

Comment: Описался  JToolBar

Comment: @Z.John Да, действительно можно. Но проблему с двойной отрисовкой области это все равно не решит, но вы правы, так и правда удобнее.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103437/discussion-between-z-john-and-konstantin-sh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так

```
public class GUI extends JPanel {

private double xn, yn, y;
private JPanel graphicsPanel;
private GraphicsArea graphicsArea;

private JButton runBut;
private JTextArea pointsInputArea;

private JPanel leftPanel;
private JToolBar toolBar;

public GUI(){

    pointsInputArea = new JTextArea();

    runBut = new JButton( new RunBtnAction() );

    toolBar = new JToolBar();
    toolBar.add(runBut);

    Dimension dimLeftPanel = new Dimension(300,400);
    leftPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    leftPanel.setMinimumSize( dimLeftPanel);
    leftPanel.setMaximumSize( dimLeftPanel);
    leftPanel.setPreferredSize( dimLeftPanel );
    leftPanel.add( new JScrollPane(pointsInputArea) );
    leftPanel.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    graphicsArea = new GraphicsArea();
    graphicsArea.setVisible( false );

    graphicsPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    graphicsPanel.add(graphicsArea);

    setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
    add( leftPanel,BorderLayout.WEST );
    add( graphicsPanel );
}

private class RunBtnAction extends AbstractAction{

    public RunBtnAction(){
        super( "Апроксиммировать" );
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
        graphicsArea.paint( getGraphics() );
        graphicsArea.setVisible( !graphicsArea.isVisible() );
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( GUI.this );
    }

}

}
```

Там проблем было несколько. Но проблема с отрисовкой была связа с тем, что операцию надо было вешать на Action. Объекты Action лучше создавать на все действия которые может делать пользователь. Так вы один раз прописываете логику и потом цепляете этот Action в разные места интерфейса (пункт меню, кнопку, сочетание клавиш )

Comment: @Konstantin_SH вам помогло данное решение? Если да голосуйте и закрывайте вопрос, если нет - пишите что не работает в комментарии.